# Django display attribute of intermediary entity through parent entity

Tags: html, django

I am trying to reference an attribute from the *Material_Requisition_Items* intermediary entity through the *Material_Requisition.reqItems* ManytoManyField and have it displayed on HTML; however, it references the *Item* parent entity instead.

**Is there a way to reference attributes from the intermediary entity through the parent in Django HTML?**

*models.py*

[Intermediary Entity]

```
class Material_Requisition_Items(models.Model):
    reqID = models.ForeignKey("Material_Requisition", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemID = models.ForeignKey('item.Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    itemQuantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
```

[Parent Entity]

```
class Material_Requisition(models.Model):
    ...
    reqItems = models.ManyToManyField(
            Item,
            through="Material_Requisition_Items",
            through_fields=('reqID', 'itemID'),
            related_name="mat_req_items"
            )
```

*requisition_detail.html*

```
{% for item in object.reqItems.all %}
<td>{{ item.itemID.itemName }}</td>
<td>{{ item.itemQuantity}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

*views.py*

```
class RequisitionDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Material_Requisition
    template_name = "requisition/requisition_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "requisition"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the relation with the `material_requisition_items_set` manager instead:

```
{% for item in object.material_requisition_items_set.all %}
    <td>{{ item.itemID.itemName }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.itemQuantity }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

You can boost efficiencly by prefetching and immediately selecting the related `itemID` with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class RequisitionDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Material_Requisition
    queryset = Material_Requisition.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('material_requisition_items_set', Material_Requisition_Items.objects.select_related('itemID'))
    )
    template_name = 'requisition/requisition_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'requisition'
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `MaterialRequisitionItems` instead of <s>`Material_Requisition_Items`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `ID` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `item`, instead of <s>`itemID`</s>.